# What would happen if we place denatured DNA in acidic medium?

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, molecular-genetics, human-genetics, dna-damage

DNA can be denatured at high temperatures or in [alkaline solutions](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21514/). But DNA can be annealed at low temperatures. I want to ask, could it be annealed in acidic medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and welcome Nandini Yadav,

It is worth mentioning DNA is an acid (*Deoxyribonucleic acid*) and [intracellular pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intracellular_pH) is most commonly between 7.0 and 7.4.

**Alkaline reagent Example**

> "The sodium hydroxide (NaOH) is a commonly used reagent to denature the DNA by increasing the pH. At an alkaline pH, OH- groups are predominant. They remove the hydrogen- bonds-contributing protons from guanine and thymine, thus breaking the hydrogen bonds between the two oligonucleotides."

[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4168728/)

You can see in the image below hydrogen bonds between nucleotides Adenine (A), Cytosine (C), Guanine (G) and Thymine (T).

[image: DNA Bonds]

**Acid reagent Example**

> A decrease in the pH was found to deteriorate the thermal stability of DNA

[Source](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/macp.1986.021870502)

At an acidic pH, the H+ in the surrounding environment of DNA is high and therefore the hydrogen bonds between Adenine (A) and Thymine (T), Cytosine (C) - Guanine (G) will 'break'.

More information [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-acids-and-bases-damage-DNA).